# Change image tag in each terraform deployement

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, terraform, continuous-deployment

I made a Gitlab pipeline to make my CI/CD, what I am looking for how can I change the name of the image on terraform code to the new image built automatically on Gitlab.

***EDIT***
this to build the image (ci)

```
    stages:
  - build_image_prod
  - build_image_dev

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

.build-setup:
    before_script:
        - cd back

  
build_container_prod:
  extends: .build-setup
  stage: build_image_prod
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "aws_ecr"
  script:
- docker build -t back:$CI_PIPELINE_IID .
    - docker tag back:$CI_PIPELINE_IID aws_ecr/back:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
    - docker push aws_ecr/back:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: always   
    - when: never
```

**And this for the terraform pipeline

```
stages:
  - init
  - workspace
  - plan 
  - apply

image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:0.13.3
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

.terraform-setup:
    before_script:
        - cd infra



init_terraform_prod:
  extends: .terraform-setup
  stage: init
  script:
    - rm -rf .terraform
    - terraform init
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
when: always
    - when: never

workspace_terraform_prod:
  extends: .terraform-setup
  stage: workspace
  script:
    - terraform workspace select prod
  dependencies:
    - init_terraform_prod
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: always
    - when: never

plan_terraform_prod:
  extends: .terraform-setup
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out "planfile"
  dependencies:
    - workspace_terraform_prod
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - infra/planfile
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: always
    - when: never
apply_terraform_prod:
  extends: .terraform-setup
  stage: apply
  when: manual
  script:
    - terraform apply -input=false "planfile" -refresh=true -target=aws_ecs_service.back -target=aws_ecs_task_definition.back  -target=aws_ecs_service.front -target=aws_ecs_task_definition.front
  dependencies:
    - plan_terraform_prod
  only: 
    - master
```

*this for the container definition of the task definition

```
 [

  {
    "name": "front",
    "image": "aws_ecr/back:latest",
    
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80
      }
    ]
    
  }

  

]
```

I want to change the image URL ("image": "aws_ecr/back:latest") of the definition everytime I do a push to deploy the latest image was build.

Comment: what do you mean by "new image" ? Docker image deployed by terraform ? Could you past terraform code where you refer to this image ?

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far, ideally as a [mcve] please? That way we can more directly help you based on what you've done already.

Comment: I added the code to make things more clear, you can found them under the EDIT

Answer (score 2):

If you're managing your ECR repository outside of terraform, you should reference it as a data resource:

```
data "aws_ecr_repository" "my_repository" {
  name = "back"
}
```

Then, in your container definition, reference it like this:

```
"${data.aws_ecr_repository.my_repository.repository_url}:latest"
```

Comment: My problem is I want to get the lastest version of the image if there is many versions in the smae ECR repository.

Comment: If you have mutable tags you can update a tag in your CICD and reference that tag. If not, you will need to update your code either manually or by CICD.